# How Make the formula for the following Concept For Sales Target

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to calculate the sales target achievable possibilities in given month.

E.g. If the sales target is 72 units per month, how can we add the formula in google sheets in percentage?

**Monthly Sales Target = 72

Units sold so far = 41

Remaining days = 10 (of the month)**

How to make the calculation or the formula for 31 (i.e. 72-41)) units needs to be achieved in remaining 10 days? (What is percentage of possibility of we can reach the target within 10 days?)

Comment: whats the desired result and how did you calculated it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see:

```
=IF((B7/B10)*100>100, 100, (B7/B10)*100)
```

[image]